Silent systemd ExecStartPre script exit code
I have a service file that starts sshd depending on the exit
of a script. The problem is I always get this when I boot:
[ Failed ] Failed to start SSH Daemon

I am aware of this, I don't want to see this error.
When I restart I get:
Job for sshd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status sshd.service" and "journalctl -xeu sshd.service" for details.

How can I suppress these errors ? I already tried redirecting to /dev/null
and a few other things.
#...
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/path/to/some/script.sh


Do you just want to silence the error (prevent it from being logged) or do you want to ignore the error (let the service start even when the pre script fails)? You're asking for the former, but I would expect you to care more about the latter.

(to make the error harmless, put a - as the first character of the value: ExecStartPre=-/path/to/some/script.sh; by the way, it's bad form to give executable scripts extensions).

@CharlesDuffy I understand that '-' ignores the error but this still runs the service even with failure which I don't want. I just want to silence the error, every time I start up I see the red error message. I already tried >/dev/null.

The maybe what you want is a ExecCondition instead of an ExecStartPre.

@CharlesDuffy I guess I overlooked that one, thanks for your help :) . If you want to post the answer I can choose it as the answer.

Not sure the question is on-topic here -- I'd argue it's a better fit to [unix.se], being more about system configuration than writing code. If it gets migrated there I'd be glad to answer, but if you want to answer it yourself here I won't object. :)

Credit to @CharlesDuffy add ExecCondition.
